# error with vagrant up librarian git chef

Tags: git, vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, librarian

I'm trying to bring up a new vagrant instance using vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef but I'm hitting a "fatal: ambiguous argument '5.x'"

I still have the previously built version of this vagrant setup else where on my computer that was have been originally setup on older versions on vagrant and virtual box and the plugins. This seems to work fine still and if i copy the "tmp" directory from the old version to the brand new dir it doesn't throw this error. I expect this error could have come in a while ago and we havn't hit it as we havn't had to spin up a brand new instance until now. 
I'm pretty new to running up vagrant with chef so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

Vagrant plugins:

```
$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-cachier (1.2.1)
vagrant-hostmanager (1.8.4)
vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef (0.2.0)
vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
```

Vagrant version: 1.8.5
Virtual Box version : 5.1.0

```
==> liquid-fe-ubuntu: Importing base box 'liquid-fe-ubuntu'...
==> liquid-fe-ubuntu: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> liquid-fe-ubuntu: Checking if box 'liquid-fe-ubuntu' is up to date...
==> liquid-fe-ubuntu: Setting the name of the VM: tron-development_liquid-fe-ubuntu_1468940599055_41479
==> liquid-fe-ubuntu: Installing Chef cookbooks with Librarian-Chef...
==> liquid-fe-ubuntu: Auto-generating node name for Chef...
==> liquid-fe-ubuntu: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/posix.rb:116:in `run!': fatal: ambiguous argument '5.x': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. (Librarian::Posix::CommandFailure)
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git/repository.rb:138:in `block in run!'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git/repository.rb:147:in `logging_command'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git/repository.rb:137:in `run!'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git/repository.rb:111:in `hash_from'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git.rb:153:in `block in fetch_sha_memo'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/environment/runtime_cache.rb:67:in `memo'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/environment/runtime_cache.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in delegate_to_backing_cache'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git.rb:152:in `fetch_sha_memo'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git.rb:92:in `cache!'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/local.rb:22:in `manifest_search_paths'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/local.rb:31:in `found_path'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:65:in `expect_manifest!'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:53:in `fetch_manifest_data'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:49:in `manifest_data'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:28:in `fetch_version'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:121:in `fetch_version!'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:113:in `fetched_version'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:59:in `version'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:97:in `satisfies?'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/dependency.rb:121:in `satisfied_by?'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:103:in `block in check_manifest'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `each'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `find'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `check_manifest'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:63:in `block in recursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block in recursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:50:in `resolve'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver.rb:23:in `resolve'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/action/resolve.rb:26:in `run'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/vagrant-librarian-chef/action/librarian_chef.rb:52:in `resolve_and_install_cookbooks'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/vagrant-librarian-chef/action/librarian_chef.rb:16:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/Users/RobM/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-cachier-1.2.1/lib/vagrant-cachier/action/configure_bucket_root.rb:20:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:78:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:74:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:561:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.5/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: What does your `Cheffile` look like?

Comment: ahaha! thank you @coderanger. 
Im suprised this didnt come up in the search i did for "5.x" in my vagrant directory.

`cookbook "mysql", :git => "https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql.git", :ref => "5.x"`

Will look to see what specific version we should be using for mysql.